# draggable - move div when dragged to specific position and mouse released

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

What I wish to achieve is that when the user drags the containing div left to a specific range and releases the mouse, the whole containing div should move -50%.

I have made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cSR6K/) to give a working general idea on what I'm after.

Currently the spot where I'm stuck at is detecting whether the mouse was released and getting the div to shift -50% from the left.

I have tried something like this:

```
$(".content-switch").draggable("option", {
  "revert": false,
  "disabled": true
});
$(".content-switch").css("left", "-50%");
$(".content-switch").draggable("option", {
  "revert": true,
  "disabled": false
});
```

As in disable the draggable, move it -50% from the left and then re-enable it (re-enable because the dragging also needs to be done vice versa later on) but that didn't work as it broke during dragging.

Is there a more straight-forward solution to achieving this e.g. in any of the draggable events themselves, or does anyone have an idea on a workaround to getting this to work.

Comment: well, `ui-draggable` has `stop` event that is triggered once you stop dragging (release), but what you've tried it's using `drag` event which is fired during the drag, docs: http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-stop

Comment: As Mendes mentioned use the stop function.  Here is an example  http://jsfiddle.net/cSR6K/2/

Comment: @G.Mendes the issue with the `stop` event was that it got fired when the draggable had finished reverting back to its original position which made it rather unsmooth. I finally went with building my own revert handle for it with setting `revert: false` and using `.animate` to make it smooth.